# How to Redirect my all post/page in Http to Https

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, redirect, https

I am using wordpress. Actually recently I updated my website with SSL certificate in that everything is done. I have added redirect code in my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But only Homepage working perfect. It's automatically redirecting
http://www.lyricstake.com to https://www.lyricstake.com, but all other pages/post requests did not get redirecting. I want redirect my all post requests automatically, for example http://www.name.com/post/ to
https://www.name.com/post/.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change all the URLs in your database from http to https. For doing this you can use this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

Make sure to take a full backup of your database before using this plugin.

Comment: It's not a good answer. I am not asking for replace url. My question is about url redirecting.